# SauceLab Curl: <27> Out of Memory

Tags: android, selenium, curl, apk, saucelabs

I am new to saucelabs.When I tried the CURL in cmd prompt to upload my apk file(in Zip mode) to saucelabs, I am getting the following "Curl: <27> Out of Memory".

Note: i am able to do it for the first time but getting the error from the next time. tried in different machine and observed the sane result